# Sending NSData inside a structure object over BlueTooth

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

The structure:

```
typedef struct 
{
    NSData *levelData;
    int levelID;
} GameLevelInfo;
```

How I send the data:

```
    static GameLevelInfo gameLevelInfo;
    gameLevelInfo.levelData = [[LevelManager sharedManager] levelDataFromName:@"XXXXXX"]];
    gameLevelInfo.levelID = 1;
    [sendPacket:NETWORK_SENDING_LEVEL
    objectIndex:0 
           data:&gameLevelInfo 
         length:sizeof(gameLevelInfo) 
       reliable:YES];
```

The "levelDataFromName":

```
-(NSData *) levelDataFromName:(NSString *)levelName
{
    NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", levelName];
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filePath];
}
```

And the "sendPacket":

```
- (void)sendPacket:(int)packetID objectIndex:(int)objectIndex data:(void *)data length:(int)length reliable:(bool)howtosend {

    // the packet we'll send is resued
    static unsigned char networkPacket[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
    const unsigned int packetHeaderSize = 3 * sizeof(int); // we have two "ints" for our header 

    if(length < (MAX_PACKET_SIZE - packetHeaderSize)) { // our networkPacket buffer size minus the size of the header info
        int *pIntData = (int *)&networkPacket[0];
        // header info
        pIntData[0] = packetNumber++;
        pIntData[1] = packetID;
        pIntData[2] = objectIndex;

        // copy data in after the header
        memcpy( &networkPacket[packetHeaderSize], data, length ); 

        NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes: networkPacket length: (length+packetHeaderSize)];
        if(howtosend == YES) { 
            [session sendDataToAllPeers:packet withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];          
        } else {
            [session sendDataToAllPeers:packet withDataMode:GKSendDataUnreliable error:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

The data was sent successfully but on the "receive side":

```
GameLevelInfo *gameLevelInfo = (GameLevelInfo*)data;
NSData *content = gameLevelInfo->levelData;
```

The "content" was invalid object.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to make it this complicated for yourself.  The way I have been handling all network traffic is through classes that implement NSCoding.  That way you can just wrap them up with an NSKeyedArchiver and send them.  Object pointers inside structs are a no-no anyway.